# Hide page scroll when clicking menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use the code below to display a mobile menu on my page.
I would like to know the following:

How to hide the page scroll bar when I click the menu button and then scroll again when I close the menu?

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     console.log( "ready!" );
     var mobileTrigger = $('.js-mobile-menu-trigger');
     var mobileMenu = $('.js-mobile-menu');

     mobileTrigger.on('click', function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('active');  
         mobileMenu.toggleClass('active');                     
         console.log('wat');        
     });   
  });
</script> 

 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

    <div class="site-header-inner">
       <button class="site-nav-trigger js-mobile-menu-trigger">
       <span class="site-nav-trigger-icon">Menu</span></button>
       <ul class="site-nav js-mobile-menu">

          <li><a class="nav-link-home"href="/">Menu</a></li>    
          <li><a class="nav-link-home"href="/">Menu</a></li>    
          <li><a class="nav-link-home"href="/">Menu</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>

   <div id="content">text text text text text </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check my this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394488/8840862

Answer (score 0):

> Use Below code it will work for You :

```
$('.js-mobile-menu-trigger').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```